# Could you please tell me the way that the subject is changed?

Tags: meaning

Recently I read the text below in which the subject is suddenly changed(from Shawn to Father) so I 've lost the trace of meaning.

Could you please tell me the way that the subject is changed?

Could you explain the hole meaning of this paragraph?

Could you please tell me to which word refer "it" (in "I think it was my father")? to "creature"?

That person was Shawn, and I was looking at him but I wasn’t seeing
him. I don’t know what I saw—what creature I conjured from that violent,
compassionate act—but I think it was my father, or perhaps my father as I
wished he were, some longed-for defender, some fanciful champion, one
who wouldn’t fling me into a storm, and who, if I was hurt, would make me
whole.

The fuller text is here:

My own memory of Shawn begins in the kitchen, perhaps two months
after the second accident.
I am making corn chowder. The door squeaks and I twist at the waist to
see who’s come in, then twist back to chop an onion.
“You gonna be a walking Popsicle stick forever?” Shawn says.
“Nope.”
“You need a chiropractor,” he says.
“Mom’ll fix it.”
“You need a chiropractor,” he says again.
The family eats, then disperses. I start the dishes. My hands are in the
hot, soapy water when I hear a step behind me and feel thick, callused
hands wrap around my skull. Before I can react, he jerks my head with a
swift, savage motion. CRACK! It’s so loud, I’m sure my head has come off
and he’s holding it. My body folds, I collapse. Everything is black but
somehow spinning. When I open my eyes moments later, his hands are
under my arms and he’s holding me upright.
“Might be a while before you can stand,” he says. “But when you can, I
need to do the other side.”
I was too dizzy, too nauseous, for the effect to be immediate. But
throughout the evening I observed small changes. I could look at the
ceiling. I could cock my head to tease Richard. Seated on the couch, I could
turn to smile at the person next to me.
That person was Shawn, and I was looking at him but I wasn’t seeing
him. I don’t know what I saw—what creature I conjured from that violent,
compassionate act—but I think it was my father, or perhaps my father as I
wished he were, some longed-for defender, some fanciful champion, one
who wouldn’t fling me into a storm, and who, if I was hurt, would make me
whole.

Comment: The hole meaning?? :) To lose track of meaning, not trace.  I don't know why the brother says she needs a chiropractor, but, notice, she doesn't turn her neck to look at him. She turns "from the waist". Her neck was hurting her already. He cracked her back for her, and that is what chiropractors typically do. A chiropractic cracking of the back/head can be very painful but also provide a lot of relief. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an allegory, or a fantasy, or actually happened.

The writer looked at Shawn, but saw his father.

Not exactly his father, but a version of his father he hoped would exist.

This is what his mind conjured from the violent therapy on his neck, which released a stream of chaotic thought.

There is a similar effect in meditation, where relaxing the grip of the mind can release a stream of ideas, some of which are not always welcome. It can be difficult to get past this stage.

Comment: @ Weather Vane  Could you tell me what the meaning of "I don’t know what I saw—what creature I conjured from that violent,
compassionate act" is?

Comment: I added something to my answer.